# Selecting country ID from topoJSON (D3)

Tags: d3.js, topojson

Im following this [tutorial](http://www.d3noob.org/2013/03/a-simple-d3js-map-explained.html)  "A simple d3.js map explained". I'd like to create a map and change the colour of a single country.

I've simplified the tutorial to show just the map in this [Plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/L0dyJboDsngOrJTe2ANh?p=info)

I think I might be able to select a country through the  id's found in the topoJSON

```
   {"type": "Polygon",
    "id": 604,
    "arcs": [
      [133, -473, -448, -378, -374, -413]
     ]
   },
```

I know that UK is "id": 826. Should I be using the id to change the colour of a single country and how do I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.filter`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#filter) to select the country you are interested in, then process it the way you want.

Example:

```
// select a country by Id and change its styling
g.selectAll('path')
  .filter(function(d) {
    return d.id === 826 
  })
.style('fill', 'red')
```

Demo: [Updated plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/136B8PnQN62eTJFQtY54?p=preview).

Comment: If I wanted to select and change the fill of all of the countries with matching id to that in my data, can I also do it this way? https://plnkr.co/edit/axloYGgL2l7264cY6NVw?p=info I'm trying  .filter(function(d) {
          return (d.id === cd["country-code"])
        })

Comment: You can do this by storing all the country codes in an array, then checking whether the countries' ids belong to that array. Here's a solution on plnkr for that: https://plnkr.co/edit/Tq5qdQFZnCb0cas0vqe1?p=preview